# Crawler is fetching relative links

Tags: python, scrapy

I have created a crawler using scrapy.The crawler is crawling the website and and fetching the links .
**Technology used:**Python,Scrapy
**Error**
The crawler is fetching relative urls because of which the scraper is not able to scrape the webpage.
I want the crawler to fetch only absoulte urls.
Please Help!!

```js
import scrapy
import os
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    # this is equivalent to what you would set in settings.py file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'file1.csv'
    }
    filePath='file1.csv'
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
     os.remove(filePath)
    else:
     print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")
    start_urls = ['https://www.jamoona.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for  title in titles:
            yield {'title': title}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer.

```
import scrapy

import os

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'feed_exporter_test'
    # this is equivalent to what you would set in settings.py file
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 'file1.csv'
    }
    filePath = 'file1.csv'
    if os.path.exists(filePath):
        os.remove(filePath)
    else:
        print("Can not delete the file as it doesn't exists")
    start_urls = ['https://www.jamoona.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            abs_url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield {'title': abs_url}
```